# Deneb vega lite visual gantt chart height {step} dynamic value

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

I am currently facing a problem with a custom Gantt chart in vega lite (Deneb power bi visual) I made based on the idea for a gantt chart from a stackoverflow topic:

[Gantt chart example using vega-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75833067/gantt-chart-example-using-vega-lite)

Everything works correctly, I just have a problem when I have a lot of tasks (I use it to visualise tasks in a project, not different projects, principle is the same though).

I want the height of each bar to be dependent on a data value in a column from the dataset that I pass a long from a PowerBI filter. I prefer to do it this way so I can manipulate the height directly from the PowerBI report. (This is to make it fit the screen and avoid the scroll bar, which causes you to not see the scale/axis anymore)

I can't make it work that the height: {step: } property can be a dynamic value. I can only insert an actual number (14 in the code snippet below).

In the sample dataset, I would like to use the Schaalwaarde column value as the step value. (it is a powerBI measure).

[Sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDgGa.png)

[Sample gantt chart visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqR23.png)

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "height": {"step": 14},
  "width": "container",
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "now()",
      "as": "now_field"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 1
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "now_field",
          "type": "temporal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "grid",
              "select": "interval",
              "bind": "scales"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "cornerRadius": 15,
            "height": {"band": 0.7}
          },
          "encoding": {
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum['Level'] == 2",
                "value": 0.5
              },
              "value": 0
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "WPnummer",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  0,
                  1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                  6,
                  7,
                  8
                ],
                "range": [
                  "#E4002B",
                  "#83D0F5",
                  "#414959",
                  "#6C223C",
                  "#ADB30A",
                  "#F39200",
                  "#F3BEB7",
                  "#454D6B"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "dx": -5
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
              "field": "TaakDuur"
            },
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum['Level'] == 2",
                "value": 1
              },
              "value": 0
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "WPnummer",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  0,
                  1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                  6,
                  7,
                  8
                ],
                "range": [
                  "#E4002B",
                  "#83D0F5",
                  "#414959",
                  "#6C223C",
                  "#ADB30A",
                  "#F39200",
                  "#F3BEB7",
                  "#454D6B"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "height": {"band": 1}
          },
          "encoding": {
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum['Level'] == 1",
                "value": 1
              },
              "value": 0
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "WPnummer",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  0,
                  1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                  6,
                  7,
                  8
                ],
                "range": [
                  "#E4002B",
                  "#83D0F5",
                  "#414959",
                  "#6C223C",
                  "#ADB30A",
                  "#F39200",
                  "#F3BEB7",
                  "#454D6B"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "center",
            "color": "white"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
              "field": "TaakDuur"
            },
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum['Level'] == 1",
                "value": 1
              },
              "value": 0
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "mid_gantt",
              "type": "temporal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "point",
            "shape": "diamond",
            "size": 150
          },
          "encoding": {
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum['MijlpaalBool'] == true",
                "value": 1
              },
              "value": 0
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "WPnummer",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  0,
                  1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                  6,
                  7,
                  8
                ],
                "range": [
                  "#E4002B",
                  "#83D0F5",
                  "#414959",
                  "#6C223C",
                  "#ADB30A",
                  "#F39200",
                  "#F3BEB7",
                  "#454D6B"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "dx": -10
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
              "field": "TaakDuur"
            },
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum['MijlpaalBool'] == true",
                "value": 1
              },
              "value": 0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "height": {"band": 1.2}
          },
          "encoding": {
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum['Sort'] == 0",
                "value": 1
              },
              "value": 0
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "WPnummer",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  0,
                  1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                  6,
                  7,
                  8
                ],
                "range": [
                  "#E4002B",
                  "#83D0F5",
                  "#414959",
                  "#6C223C",
                  "#ADB30A",
                  "#F39200",
                  "#F3BEB7",
                  "#454D6B"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "center",
            "color": "white"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
              "field": "TaakDuur"
            },
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": "datum['Sort'] == 0",
                "value": 1
              },
              "value": 0
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "mid_gantt",
              "type": "temporal"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Startdatum_gantt",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": null,
            "grid": true,
            "format": "%d%b%y",
            "orient": "bottom"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "TaakDuur",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "sort": {"field": "Sort"},
          "axis": {
            "title": null,
            "grid": false,
            "labels": false,
            "tickBand": "extent"
          }
        },
        "x2": {
          "field": "Einddatum_gantt",
          "type": "temporal"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "Taak"},
          {"field": "Startdatum"},
          {"field": "Einddatum"},
          {"field": "Duur"}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I managed to do this with a bind parameter, but I prefer not to do it this way; I want to do it from a powerBI filter because I use the visual embedded in ppt and the vega slider ruins it a bit. My backup plan is just to make 5 different reports with 5 different step heights, but this seems a little silly to me and I assume there should be an easy solution. I just can't figure out how to reference the data in a column from my dataset in height {step}.

I also want to avoid using autosize or height: container because if there are not a lot of tasks in my project it will stretch the entire visual in a weird way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working how I want it. I don't know why I was fixated on doing it with the step interval. I changed my measure to indicate the height and then added a height parameter:

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "height",
      "expr": "data('dataset')[0]['Schaalwaarde']"
    }
  ],
   "height": 680,...
```